# Select documents by range of _id values in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating an application that allows the user to create subtables from master tables, where he/she can specify a range of rows to be included in the subtable.

This is my Subtable model:

```
 // Imports
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const timestamps = require('mongoose-timestamp');
// Setup
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ViewSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  table: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'Table'
  },
  range: [
    [
      {
        start: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Row' },
        end: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Row' }
      }
    ]
  ],
  columns: {
    type: Object,
    required: true
  }
});

ViewSchema.plugin(timestamps);

module.exports = mongoose.model('View', ViewSchema);
```

I currently store the starting row of the range and the ending row.

Now I wanted to know that if there is a way I can select only the documents that are inserted after the starting row and before the ending row so I don't have to pull 1000's of rows and filter them on the client side.

And if this is not possible, then I would love to know about any other solution.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You should not do this by _id but by createdDate. Start and end can be createdDate of whichever you want start and end document. You can retrieve data from start and end date range.

Answer (score 1):

A very naive solution to do this is using `$gt` and `$lt` operators, like this:

```
RowModel.find({ _id: { $gt: ObjectIdOfTheStart, $lt: ObjectIdOfTheEnd } });
```

So this will return all the rows which have an ObjectId greater than that of the start row and lower than that of the end row.

More on [$gt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) and [$lt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/).

Also as @the_mahasagar mentioned that you must use something like start and end dates, querying ObjectId does the same as well, as mentioned by Steve Ridout [here](https://steveridout.github.io/mongo-object-time/).

**Word of caution**, I wouldn't recommend doing something like this. you should use some other kind of identifier for querying these rows.